# Problem with PUT request in axios with vue.js

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm building a smart home application. I have a problem with sending PUT request to my rest api (I building it with flask), but when I try send request it gives me HTTP 400 error (( Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400 )) . Can you help me?

```
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            value: 0,
            lampName: 'Kitchen',
        };
    },
    mounted () {
        axios
        .get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/lamp/" + this.$route.params.id)
        .then(response => (this.value = response.data))
    },
    methods: {
        updateValue () {
            axios
                .put('http://127.0.0.1:5000/lamp/' + this.$route.params.id,
                {value: this.value},
                {headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try .catch(error => console.log(error))

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it still doesn't work and don't print any more informations in console.

Answer (score 1):

try to add the method field to the form and send it in post way like this

```
formData.append('_method', 'PUT')
```

then try to send the data regularly
I think it work like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js">
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            value: 0,
            lampName: 'Kitchen',
        };
    },
    mounted () {
        axios
        .get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/lamp/" + this.$route.params.id)
        .then(response => (this.value = response.data))
    },
    methods: {
        updateValue () {
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("value", this.value);
            formData.append("lampName", this.lampName);
            formData.append('_method', 'PUT');

            axios
                .post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/lamp/' + this.$route.params.id,
                formData
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Tanaten you saved my day just now, thank you. I did not know that I had to append the REST method to the form data on a put when using axios.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the failing request:

```js
axios
    .put('http://127.0.0.1:5000/lamp/' + this.$route.params.id,
    {value: this.value},
    {headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    }
})
```

I don't know what your server is expecting but you're setting a `content-type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` while sending JSON data. It seems likely this mismatch is the cause of your problems. You should be able to see this if you inspect the request in the **Network** section of your browser's developer tools.

If you need to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then I suggest reading the axios documentation as you can't just pass in a data object like that:

https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

In short, you need to build up the body string manually, though there are utilities to make that less onerous.

If you actually want JSON data then just remove the `content-type` header. Axios should set a suitable `content-type` for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Pass your method as post method and define put in form data `formData.append('_method', 'PUT')` .

```
     updateValue () {
            axios
                .post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/lamp/' + this.$route.params.id,
                {value: this.value, _method: 'PUT'},
                {headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                }
            })
        }
```